# How do you determine whether a USB-C ethernet adapter is compatible?

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, internet, ethernet

I'm shopping for a USB-C ethernet adapter compatible with all OS. Is there a way to verify it will work for lubuntu or ubuntu prior to purchase?

[Techkey's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XLLTL7V) description says "Supported Operating Systems: Windows XP and above(32/64-bit), Mac OS X10.6 and above", but does not mention the linux kernel. (A different search result explicitly stated manual installation would be required for linux 4.8 and prior, alerting me to potential incompatibility.)

[Flujo](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075L5HQXG)'s description says "OTG device, Used with no external drivers or power required."

So is Flujo's more likely to work than Techkey's? What do you look for?

Comment: "OTG" means that it's supported on on-the-go devices like android, etc.  Supported Operating Systems usually don't refer to Linux.  ("Manual Installation" means the drivers).  If you are using Ubuntu 18.04 or newer that's on 4.15 kernel or later.  (Which means you don't need manual installation there).  Chances are if you're on a recent release (18.04 or newer) it *should* work with the system out of the box.  Usually that's because chipset drivers weren't shipped with the kernel prior to 4.9+ (which happens sometimes).

Comment: Does '4.15' mean 'April 2015' and '4.8' 'April 2008' release dates? (Your comment suggests that 4.15 is newer than 4.8.)

Comment: No, that's the Linux Kernel numbering scheme.  Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/843197/what-are-kernel-version-number-components-w-x-yy-zzz-called  And 4.15 **is** newer than 4.8.  (The Kernel numbers don't correspond to release dates, only the Ubuntu release numbering scheme corresponds to Month/Date)

Comment: What does it mean for an ethernet adapter to be an on-the-go device? Wikipedia says the term refers to something that can either process data (e.g. smartphone reading photos from a memory card) or be a host for data (e.g. have data pulled from it when connected to PC). Why would you call a signal-converter (isn't that what this adapter is?) an OTG device?

Comment: > USB On-The-Go (USB OTG or just OTG) is a specification first used in late 2001 that allows USB devices, such as tablets or smartphones, to act as a host, allowing other USB devices, such as USB flash drives, digital cameras, mice or keyboards, to be attached to them. Use of USB OTG allows those devices to switch back and forth between the roles of host and device. A mobile phone may read from removable media as the host device, but present itself as a USB Mass Storage Device when connected to a host computer.  --src: Wikipedia

Comment: I would google make and model with linux drivers.  If found good chance it will work.

Comment: So what happened, which one did you buy @InternetUser ?